# How to dynamically name element in angular

Tags: angular, viewchild

I want to create components dynamically from an array. #cmp1, #cmp2, #cmp3 should be dynamic how can this be achieved

```
 <my-component #cmp1></my-component> 
 <my-component #cmp2></my-component> 
 <my-component #cmp3></my-component> 

 componentList: string[] = ['cmp1', 'cmp2', 'cmp3']
```

And I have to fetch one these components dynamically at runtime based on a string value

```
 let reqiuredComponent = 'cmp2'
 let captureComponent: MyComponent = @ViewChild(requiredComponent)
```

Comment: Why not use ViewChildren? You get a QueryList of your components, and you can get first, pass to array....

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved without assigning dynamic template reference `[#cp1, #cp2 ...]` also.

In your **.html**

```
<div #container>
 <ng-container #main></ng-container>
</div>
```

In your **.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('main', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vcr: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() { 
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++) {
      this.vcr.createComponent(this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent)); 
    }           
  }
```

Now to **access** your different component

```
console.log(this.container.nativeElement.childNodes[1]     //childNodes[0|1|2]
```

Like this you can assess all the functionality of `ElementRef` like `...childNodes[0].innerHTML`

Comment: let comp1: MyCustomComponent = ..childNodes[0].innerHTML;

can i assign .innerHTML to MyCustomComponent Class type ?

Comment: you can, but i don't understand the reason you wanna do that.

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple dynamically created components, you can fetch one of these components dynamically at runtime by ViewChildren

in parent component:

```
import { .., ViewChildren,QueryList } from '@angular/core';
...
@ViewChildren(MyComponent) mycomponents!: QueryList<MyComponent>;
// now you can fetch second component by:
this.mycomponents.toArray()[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving directions towards ViewChildren. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren lists some other options to use it.